# Pie chart in Excel 2010 is not reading/displaying the number 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I am trying to create a very basic pie chart in Excel with the following data:

```
Score          Quantity
0              5
1              5
2              6
3              3
4              4
5              8
6              7
7             16
8             38
9             48
10            99
```

When I highlight the data cells in excel and create a simple 2D pie chart, the chart looks as follows:

[image: Click Here for Chart]

Does anyone know why Excel is ignoring the 0 - The data clearly states that there is a quantity of 5 for the Score of 0. Is there a setting that I have missed somewhere? I have tried changing the cell formatting to General, Number & Text to no avail.

Comment: It's plotting the score instead of the quantity (and calculating the percentages based on the score label).  Plot the quantity and specify the score column as the data labels.

Comment: This answer has solved my query - but I'm unable to mark as solved.

Comment: I don't have immediate access to Excel and couldn't verify the exact menu selections, so I posted a comment.  If you can write up an answer, you'll be able to accept it in two days.  A good quality answer is likely to attract some upvotes, which will build you some rep on the site.  BTW, if you want to include some screenshots, just use a link like you did in the question.  I, or someone else on the site, will be happy to embed the image.

Comment: OK, I'll go ahead and close the loop with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pie charts plot a single column of data, the leftmost if you select multiple columns.  The problem was that in selecting all of the data, Excel defaulted to plotting the Score column instead of the Quantity (and calculating the percentages based on the score label).

If you're starting from scratch, select just the column you want to graph (Quantity in this case).  You can then tell Excel to use the Score column for labels.  Since you've already selected all of the data and created a chart, I'll provide instructions for correcting the setup.

Double-click on the pie, then right-click and pick `Select Data`.  You'll see `Score` and `Quantity` both listed as series.  Select `Score` and click `Remove`.

Select `Quantity`.  On the right side are the axis labels.  Click `Edit', and specify the range for the Score values (A2:A12).  Click`OK` to exit.

[image: screenshot1]

Now the graph will be plotting the `Quantities` and calculating percentages based on them.  The additional formatting options are accessible from context menus clicking on the chart.

[image: screenshot2]